# Creating a library to have rabbit spring beans created

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am creating a message bus jar which connects to different MQ broker like Rabbit MQ. The jar will be used by many applications to send and receive message from Rabbit.
While sending message is working as expected from my application, not clear about how to design the listener. Obviously the @RabbitListener is in the jar but I want the message should reach the class in applications.
Any suggestions appreciated.
Is there any better way to create a kind of bus library for rabbit spring and use in applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make yourself familiar with https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. And also take a look, please, into this project which already implements something similar: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus